# Pentaho Reporting without Datasource

Tags: json, report, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am possible to create a report without datasource connection?

for example,

I have a link with JSON return and in pentaho report.

I'mnot using datasource connection like `JDBC/ODBC/JNDI`, just hit an URL then the URL will return JSON data, this data will show up in detail section.

am i possible?

i tried to search something in google, but i still have no idea.

I am using `Pentaho Report Designer 5.3.0.0`, i tried to ask in `pentaho forums` too.. but theres no answer for me :(

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Creating a CDA with the result of the web service (link json), this is passed to the pentaho report designer by clicking on the tab data, right click data sets, and then Community Data Acces, there are settings and you choose the CDA that you created previously
2. You can create a transformation with the pdi, from the transformation you can easily consume the web service, and treat the data, then pass this as datasource of the report designer

[image: pentaho report designer datasource]